# Use abbrev to expand "-->"

Tags: abbrev

I want to type "--> " and have it automatically converted into "→ ".  Is there a way to do this using Abbrev?

Comment: Do you mean expand `—>` to `\rightarrow`?

Answer (score 2):

From emacs manual:

> More precisely, any character that is not a word constituent expands an abbrev, and any word-constituent character can be part of an abbrev.

So the answer is no because characters '-' and '>' are not word characters.

Instead, do come up a with naming schema that is easy to remember. I am using the convention from Xah Lee to start Unicode abbrevs with character 8 and use a short mnemonic string. For example, add this into your global-abbrev-table:

```
("8ar" "→" nil 0)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about what to change in abbrev.el so that what's a "word" can be defined by the user.  It seems that abbrev.el uses the regexp "\\w+".  My suggestion for the developers would be to make this user-configurable.  I f.ex., would like to set it to "[a-zA-Z0-9<>-]+".

Answer (score 1):

Using abbrev, not really.  You can do it yourself though:

```
(defun my-insert-gt ()
  "Substitute in arrow maybe."
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-back "--" (- (point) 2))
      (progn
        (backward-delete-char 2)
        (insert "→"))
    (insert ">")))
(global-set-key ">" #'my-insert-gt)
```