# Can I use an abbrev that starts with a backslash?

Tags: abbrev

I want to type certain unicode characters using backslashes, but it seems that `abbrev-mode` ignores such strings.

For example, I'd like `\approx` to expand to `≈`.

If I have this:

```
(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table
  '(
    ("\\approx" "≈" nil :count 0)
    ("foo" "find outer otter" nil :count 3)
   ))
```

The first one doesn't work, but `foo` does. Is there a way to use this kind of "abbreviation" in Emacs?

Comment: What happens if you delete the backslashes? Does it work then? If so, it would seem to indicate that the name of the abbrev has to start with a letter (but I have *not* checked).

Comment: It looks as if abbrevs have to consist of characters that are "word  constituents" - which I take to mean that their syntax class is `word` - but I have not gone deeply into it. Try `ESC ESC : (abbrev--before-point)` which should return the abbrev name if recognized or `nil` if it does not. It returns `nil` after `\approx`.

Comment: Yup, it's `nil`, and if I remove the backslashes it works. I now see someone asked about this before: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42102/use-abbrev-to-expand. My goal is to insert unicode quickly, so maybe I can try another route. I can use `insert-char` and auto-complete the character names. But I'd I need to adjust the completion there, so I don't have to type as much or mouse click from the list.

Comment: Thanks for finding that: your question should then probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Yup, it's a dupe. I don't see why abbrev should be restricted to \w. I may try changing the .el code.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/66434/454 is another dup which might help.